# How to open a subfolder and find path by using os.listdir

Tags: python

I want to read all images in a sub-folder, named `digit_test` by `os.listdir`:

```
file_pathname = './digit_test'
for filename in os.listdir(file_pathname):
    print(filename)
    img = cv2.imread(file_pathname+'/'+filename)
```

However, it shows Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError

```
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the specified path.: './digit_test'
  File "D:\Python_ex\lenet_5\lenet_5_isvalid.py", line 15, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir(file_pathname):
```

the file structure like that,

```
lenet_5>-my_test.py
        -digit_test-> 0.PNG
```

I was wondering if it is correponding to the relative path, because when I use absolute path, it can work now.

```
file_pathname = r'D:\Python_ex\lenet_5\digit_test'
```

Besides,

```
file_pathname = r'.\lenet_5\digit_test'
```

also can work now.

Actually, it is problem like that, the main folder includes a python file and secondary folder, and the secondary folder includes some imgs, now I just want to read these imgs in this python file. However, if I use a absolute path, it cannot still work when I change the folder name.

Comment: Print out the value of `file_pathname+'/'+filename`. The message is telling you that it is not precisely the same as `'./digit_test/0.PNG'`. (I am well aware that you are certain that it is the same.)

Comment: @BoarGules Hi, thanks for your reply again, could you please have a look, I revise some part of question

Comment: And so now you are getting expected results with the variable `file_name_1` but not with the variable `file_name`? That tells you what the problem is.

Comment: @BoarGulesB Sorry, maybe I miss the main problem, I mean why it cannot find my folder by os.listdir(), besides why it can be find when I add "lenet_5"-the upper directory into the path

Comment: From which folder are you executing your python code? Because that will affect your relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to add full error log for better helps, but my guess is, you executed script outside the script's path.

In short, you might have executed script *INSIDE* `lenet_5` first, then on next runs you either did `os.chdir` or executed script *OUTSIDE* it, seemingly `Python_ex`

In terminal, the directory you are currently in terminal become current working directory for any script you run.

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir("./exported")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] 지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다: './exported'

[WinError 3] 지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다: './exported'

# current working directory is not where I intended
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\jupiterbjy'

# now change directory to where I want to be

>>> os.chdir("E:/Media/Works/CSP")
>>> os.listdir("./exported")
['banners', 'bg2.png', 'box.png', ...

>>> os.getcwd()
'E:\\Media\\Works\\CSP'
```

---

#### Old answer

Why not try out much superior alternative `pathlib.Path`?

if os.listdir is absolutely needed you can just convert it into string and feed the string-fied path into os.listdir.

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> root = pathlib.Path("./")
>>> root
WindowsPath('.')

>>> root.absolute().as_posix()
'E:/Media/Works/CSP/Exported'

>>> root.joinpath("banners").absolute()
WindowsPath('E:/Media/Works/CSP/Exported/banners')

>>> def images_gen():
...     for path in root.iterdir():
...         if path.suffix in (".png", ".jpg"):
...             yield path

>>> import pprint
>>> images = list(images_gen())
>>> pprint.pprint(images)
[WindowsPath('bg2.png'),
 WindowsPath('box.png'),
...

>>> data = images[0].read_bytes()
>>> len(data)
81245


# pathlib.Path features

>>> pprint.pprint([method for method in dir(root) if not method.startswith("_")])
['absolute',
 'anchor',
 'as_posix',
 'as_uri',
 'chmod',
 'cwd',
 'drive',
 'exists',
 'expanduser',
 'glob',
 'group',
 'hardlink_to',
 'home',
 'is_absolute',
 'is_block_device',
 'is_char_device',
 'is_dir',
 'is_fifo',
 'is_file',
 'is_mount',
 'is_relative_to',
 'is_reserved',
 'is_socket',
 'is_symlink',
 'iterdir',
 'joinpath',
 'lchmod',
 'link_to',
 'lstat',
 'match',
 'mkdir',
 'name',
 'open',
 'owner',
 'parent',
 'parents',
 'parts',
 'read_bytes',
 'read_text',
 'readlink',
 'relative_to',
 'rename',
 'replace',
 'resolve',
 'rglob',
 'rmdir',
 'root',
 'samefile',
 'stat',
 'stem',
 'suffix',
 'suffixes',
 'symlink_to',
 'touch',
 'unlink',
 'with_name',
 'with_stem',
 'with_suffix',
 'write_bytes',
 'write_text']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply again but I guess the main problem is why it cannot find my folder by os.listdir(), besides why it can be find when I add "lenet_5"-the upper directory into the path

Comment: Oh I totally misunderstood the question, mybad. I just tried on my system and I don't see any problem loading, did you changed directory while script is running? I think we need more details on it, as much as we can think of.

Comment: Is it work in your PC? I mean, the main folder include a python file and secondary folder, and the secondary folder includes some imgs, now I just want to read these imgs in python file

Comment: Hmm... I think I saw similar case using pycharm(usually due to their cwd settings) or when using os.chdir, since then I ditched os path functions, lemme check
Obviously if you run script from script's folder and outside of it have different cwd.

Comment: @4daJKong okay, updated answer, double check your cwd and lemme know.